# Pylint - Too many boolean expressions in if statement

Tags: python, django

Buenas tardes tengo el siguiente fragmento de código:

```
content_view = cleaned_data.get('content_view')
show_content = cleaned_data.get('show_content')
show_children = cleaned_data.get('show_children')

footer_title_1 = cleaned_data.get('footer_title_1')
footer_link_1 = cleaned_data.get('footer_link_1')
footer_image_1 = cleaned_data.get('footer_image_1')
footer_title_2 = cleaned_data.get('footer_title_2')
footer_link_2 = cleaned_data.get('footer_link_2')
footer_image_2 = cleaned_data.get('footer_image_2')
footer_title_3 = cleaned_data.get('footer_title_3')
footer_link_3 = cleaned_data.get('footer_link_3')
footer_image_3 = cleaned_data.get('footer_image_3')

if not self.object and not parent:
    msg = u'No se puede crear páginas del primer nivel.'
    self.add_error('parent', msg)

if not image and not parent:
    msg = u'La página del primer nivel debe tener una imagen.'
    self.add_error('image', msg)

if show_children and not content_view:
    msg = u'Tiene que elegir la forma de mostrar a los hijos.'
    self.add_error('content_view', msg)

if not show_children and not show_content:
    msg = u'Tiene que elegir qué mostrar en la página: ' \
          u'el contenigo, los hijos o ambos.'
    self.add_error('show_content', msg)

if (
    footer_title_1 or footer_link_1 or footer_image_1 or
    footer_title_2 or footer_link_2 or footer_image_2 or
    footer_title_3 or footer_link_3 or footer_image_3
) and not (
    footer_title_1 and footer_link_1 and footer_image_1 and
    footer_title_2 and footer_link_2 and footer_image_2 and
    footer_title_3 and footer_link_3 and footer_image_3
):
    msg = u'Tiene que completar todos los campos \
          de los bloques inferiores de la página.'
    self.add_error(None, msg)
```

quisiera saber de que forma podria refactorizarlo? puesto que pylint me arroja alerta por tener mas de 5 condiciones.

Comment: A menos que hayas definido esos campos como blank=true, son obligatorios y no hay necesidad de hacer esas validaciones. Si es un campo personalizado, puedes inicializarlo marcándolos como `footer_title_2.required = true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te dice @toledano, lo mejor es aprovechar las facilidadesd de django para controlar el formulario.

Pero para responder a tu pregunta, es posible reducir la cadena de comprobaciones utilizando las funciones `all` y `any` quedando mucho más *legible*:

```
footers = [footer_title_1, footer_link_1, footer_image_1,
           footer_title_2, footer_link_2, footer_image_2,
           footer_title_3, footer_link_3, footer_image_3 ]

if any(footers) and not all(footers):
   ...
```

Aún se puede hacer mejor para evitar tener que comprobar cada elemento dos veces:

```
if len(footers) > sum(1 for f in footers if f) >= 1:
   ...
```